# Generalization of strings and state machine optimization

Tags: regex, algorithm, optimization, nlp, state-machine

I am looking into learning state machines that accept given samplings of a regular language, you can allow or disallow noise in the sampling, lets assume no noise for simplicity.

Example:

given the strings ['fun', 'gun'] I can construct the regex 'fun|gun' but a shorter regex description is '[fg]un', I wish to find this systematically.

I've seen papers teaching the language to an RNN and then extracting a state machine from that RNN in various approximational weirding ways, which is kind of strange, cause I also seem to vaguely remember from my Computer Science days that the question of optimizing a state machine is a fairly well studied and solved problem. If the second is true, why not simply start with any state machine that accepts the language and then optimize it in terms of state or something?

Are there in short any *regular expression/state machine* optimization algorithm in python I can use in some obscure package cause I'm not managing to find either an algorithm or a package implementing it, just some vague CS lecture slides.

Answer (score 2):

Minimizing a regular expression and minimizing a state machine are very different problems. Indeed, while DFAs and regular expressions are equally expressive (they can describe exactly the same languages), there is no simple relationship between the sizes of the representations. There are DFAs which requires regular expressions of size exponential in the number of states, and regular expressions which blowup exponentially when converted to DFAs (even with minimization). Also, minimizing the size of a regular expression is basically intractable, unlike minimizing the states in a DFA. (There are "approximately minimal" algorithms, but they're not pretty.)

There is no package in the standard Python library to do these tasks. Bad and copy-protected implementations (sometimes even two-in-one) abound on the internet; for some reason, almost all the implementations seem to be done either by students who are still learning whatever language they are writing in, or academics who think that their work is too precious to share as open-source. In any event, the preceding snark is an example of why SO discourages "find me a resource" questions: they tend to attract opinionated responses which are not particularly helpful to anyone (other than, perhaps, scratching an itch of the responder).

If you're going to program it, the algorithms are actually pretty straight-forward. The Thompson construction to convert regex to NFA shouldn't be more than a hundred lines of Python, and the powerset construction to produce a DFA is even simpler. Once you have NFA->DFA, you can do minimization using Brzozowski's algorithm, which is trivial: reverse the DFA producing an NFA, reduce that back to a DFA, and then reverse and reduce again. It's not obvious why that works, but it does work and it's a single line of code once you've written the DFA reverser, which in turn is half a dozen lines.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the algorithms you mentioned, but I don't understand the claim, will the DFA->NFA->DFA loops insure ending in a minimal DFA? Also... shouldn't there be some balancing parameter between generalization and overfitting of the samples?

Comment: @veltzer: Yes, if you start with a DFA and do two iterations of reverse/convert to DFA, then you get a minimal DFA. The proof is too long to fit in a comment, but you should be able to find it easily enough. (Search for Brzozowski minimization.)

Comment: As for generalization and overfitting, that's outside of the scope of this answer :-) You just asked for a Python library which could minimize regular expressions or state machines, and that's what I tried to address. But certainly you need to deal with generalization. For example, both the regular expression and the state machine for any finite subset of `a*` are linear in the size of the subset, but `a*` itself is just two symbols and the state machine has just two states.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the translations between regex and state machine, isn't this what standard packages do? I mean, there's even a debug mode in python where you print out the resulting state machine. Could you give an example or link to such an exploding state regex?"

Comment: @VeltzerDoron: Yes, most regex libraries do some kind of regex->NFA mapping. But few if any allow you to see the resulting NFA. And very few do the NFA->DFA mapping, because for a regex library it's better to do that lazily; most DFA states will never be needed. The classic regex with exponential state count is `(a|b)*a(a|b){N}`; see [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/6065/4416) from [cs.se] for an explanation. There's also a very elegant NFA with exponential blow-up in [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3381/nfa-with-exponential-number-of-states-when-deteminized)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, linking to the computer science topic however was uncalled for :)

Comment: @veltzer: if the link you're complaining about is [cs.se], that's what happens when you put the code for a sister site into a comment. I just typed `[cs.se]`